# Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 allow svg upload

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi Whenever i am trying to upload svg image file in products it keeps saying "Disallowed file type". Already added file extension like this:

```
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','svg'));
```

in:
`Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php`

`Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php`

**Do i need to add 'svg' in other then those 3 core files also? 
My Magento ver. is 1.9.2.4**

Thanks